# leaflet, use html select to choose city and located in map

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, leaflet

I can select city in my html page, and I want to locate the city on my leaflet map base on each my selection.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="city" id="select" onchange="shift_city()">
              <option value="camera1">Hungary, Oroshaza</option>
              <option value="camera2">Korea, Gosunguhwi</option>
              <option value="camera3">Canada, Toronto</option>
</select>
```

Here is my js code:

```
function shift_city(){
    var value_city=document.getElementById("select").value;

    $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx", 
                dataType: "json",
                headers: { "fiware-service": "smartcity" , "fiware-servicepath": "/"},
                error:function(e){
                        console.log(e);
                        alert("noooooo");
                },
                success: function (data) {

                   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                      if(value_city==data[i].id.value){

                             var lat=data[i].latitude.value;
                             var lng=data[i].longitude.value; 
                             map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), 8);
                      }
                     }


                }  
    });



}
```

Inside the Ajax there are 2 headers, so I could get filtered query result. However, I can get the correct data only if I select just 1 time, but if I want to re-select city without reload js, I got raw data without filter, like I made a query without headers.
I don't understand why this happened? 
The city didn't locate on map as well.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Does your list of cities change so often that you need to perform a new AJAX request every time the page is loaded, rather than hard-coding their coordinates?

Comment: the function I want to realize is to change map view by selection. are there any other ideas? put ajax outside shift_city and take data value?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I improved my function by calling ajax just once and use data for an outside function. 
outside ajxa:
var myData=data;

Then inside function shift_city() get myData